# Multiple socket messages compressed in one

Tags: c#, node.js, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to do a program which communicate from local NodeJS to a C# Socket server.

Here's the code I'm using

**NodeJS**

```
const net = require('net');

class Socket {

    constructor(ip, port) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
    }

    initClient() {
        const client = new net.Socket();

        client.connect(this.port, this.ip, () => {
            console.log(`Connected to ${this.ip}:${this.port}`);
        });

        client.on("data", async data => {
            console.log("Received '" + data.toString() + "'");
            setTimeout(function () {
                client.write("OK");
            }, 3500);

        });

        client.on('close', () => {
            console.log(`Connection closed`);
        });

    }
}

let socket = new Socket("HOST", 1337);
socket.initClient();
```

**C#**

Main Class

```
List<String> toSendList = new List<String>();
toSendList.Add("TEST 1");
toSendList.Add("TEST 2");
toSendList.Add("TEST 3");
toSendList.Add("TEST 4");
toSendList.Add("TEST 5");

Parallel.ForEach(toSendList, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, delegate (string content)
{

    logger.WriteLine("Result => " + socket.SendAndWaitResult(content));

});
```

Server Socket Class

```
public Server(int port)
{

    IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    socket.Bind(ip);
    socket.Listen(10);

    client = socket.Accept();

}

public String SendAndWaitResult(String content)
{

    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
    client.Send(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None);

    data = new byte[1024];
    int receivedDataLength = client.Receive(data);
    string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, receivedDataLength);

    logger.WriteLine("[DEBUG] Received : '" + response + "'");

    return response;

}
```

And when I run both programs, here's what I get

**NodeJS Output**

```
Connected to HOST:1337
Received 'TEST 1'
Received 'TEST 2TEST 3TEST 4TEST 5'
```

**C# Output**

```
[DEBUG] Received : 'OK'
Result => OK
[DEBUG] Received : 'OK'
Result => OK
```

Does someone have an idea of why all the messages after the first one are compacted in one big message?

Comment: Basically that's how TCP works. TCP gives you a byte stream, it is not message based. A receive call can read multiple or partial data of what the other end sent using Send() calls.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is most probably the following ([source C# API Send()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.send?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_Send_System_Byte___)):

> To increase network efficiency, the underlying system may delay transmission until a significant amount of outgoing data is collected.

So even though `Send` is called individually for each entry in the List, the operating system might indeterministically join them into one TCP segment.

If you would like to discern the individual data items, you should add a seperator to the transmission. For example, use a line feed (`\n`) after each item and split them on the Node side.

```
client.on('data', data => data.toString().split('\n').forEach(item => {
  console.log(`Received '${item}'`);
  setTimeout(() => client.write('OK'), 3500);
}));
```

If the size of the individual transmission does not fit into one TCP segment additional buffering of the received segments might be necessary on the Node.js side.

Comment: Thanks! It fixed my problem, but now I have a new one.
After replacing `setTimeout(() => client.write('OK'), 3500);` by the original action (which is solving a captcha), when the NodeJS Client receive 2 requests composed of a URL and a Data SiteKey (Used for google recaptcha's), it solve the 2 requests then send back only one solution to the server, have any idea why? https://hastebin.com/azecajeruc.js

Comment: @PeterWave please create a new Question for your new problem. 1. you will get a bigger audience for the problem. 2. The solution can be found by others with the same problem.